# Is there a category of categories?

Tags: category-theory

My question is quite simple, I would like to know if we can define the category of the categories, unlike **Cat** which is the category of the small categories. By the way, are there any particular reason why we define **Cat** in this way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no category of categories, because of size issues. See [this answer][1].


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/717993/2614

Comment: @BrunoStonek I don't think the answer gives the question enough credit, since there is a _thing_ called $\mathbf{CAT}$, which [some](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0063101#page-1) [people](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/03/review_of_the_elements_of_2cat.html) even call a category. My knowledge about this stuff is not sufficiant enough to give a good answer, though....

Comment: @roman: true enough. I remember "The joy of cats" calling it a "quasicategory", although I don't think I even read how they defined that concept.

Answer (score 14):

No, there is no category of all categories. Likewise, there is no "set of all sets" or "class of all classes" or..."mother of all mothers". Think about it: *the mother* of all mothers, if it existed, would be a mother (by definition), so she would have to be the mother of herself. Pretty akward.

Nevertheless, in mathematics it is important to be able to consider the collection of all categories (small and large) and the morphisms between them (functors). This collection is given the name CAT, but it is not a category itself for the same Russel's paradox type of argument given above. CAT is a *quasicategory* or a *metacategory* or something *super...* to indicate that it belongs to a higher hierarchy of structures.
In "the joy of cats" book CAT is a called a quasicategory, but this name is now being used in another sense by most authors.
I would encourage you to read the [book](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf), since it gives a good understanding of the size issues involved and an excellent intro to category theory.

Comment: Is the reason why there is no category of category the same as in set theory, to avoid Russell's paradox?

Comment: @user132181 Yes, sort of. See my first answer to the OP.

Comment: Be careful on the notion of quasicategory http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicategory

Comment: Exactly @Lano. That's what I meant when I wrote that the term "quasicategory" is being used in another sense now.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read it thoroughly!

Answer (score -2):

In a certain sense, yes, there is, but it's not a category. There is a 2-category of "all" categories, given a choice of a Grothendieck universe. Have a look here:
http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cat